# Android getting parameter from one method to another method in other class

Tags: android

Iam trying to set searchview on my activity.I need to to pass the value everytime to the asynchronous task when user type the search keyword on searchview.
i want to pass the parameter 'query' from this method

```
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                   //want this  'string query' for further processing..

                    return true;
```

To this LoadIdioms class>>String doinBackground->> 
to this line>> params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword",query));

```
class LoadIdioms extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading IDIOMS. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Idioms from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //value captured from previous intent
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword",query));     

  class LoadIdioms extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading IDIOMS. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Idioms from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //value captured from previous intent
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword",searchkey));
```

How we can easily do that,help me programmers..

Comment: How about using a setter method for the variable in the AsyncTask. You could call it from your Activity and manipulate the value of it.

Comment: how,can u post it as an answer please.. bcoz iam beginner to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i decided to change my coding into like this way

```
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                    searchkey=query;
                    new LoadIdioms().execute();
                    lv = getListView();


                    return true;
```

Here i called asynchrnous task class within onquerytextchange method,so it will call each time when text change occurs instead of passing parameteter value.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Boolean value returned from that method into a declared string variable. Then you can try calling it in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value into the `AsyncTask` in this manner

```
LoadIdioms  task= new LoadIdioms();
task.execute(query);
```

And use it in the `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask` in this manner

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyword",args[0]));
```